# 2 Laravel apps, only one can login

Tags: authentication, laravel-4

I'm creating a web app and I need to deploy it as multiple web app instance
Let's say I'm deploying app as

```
root    
  |_ app1
  |_ app2
  |_ app3
```

Both `app2` dan `app3` are cloned from `app1` via git. After that I do `composer install` and let them installs..

everything went fine when I log in to `app1`, but after logging in to `app2`, My `app1` login was logged-out without clear reason. My first verdict was the session colliding, but I don't find any lead changing Laravel session key... So I tried changing the App Key but it doesn't do anything.

Anyone can point me some lead or answer? Thank you

P.S: I access the via subfolder (eg: `http://mydomain/app1`, `http://mydomain/app2`, `http://mydomain/app3` )

---

Things I've tried:

- changing App Key
- changing session.cookie and assign different names
  to each site

Edit: `changing session.cookie and assign different names
   to each site` is the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `session.cookie` is the correct solution!

Start creating `session.php` on config and put different values for `cookie` for each app

```
<?php
return [
    'cookie' => 'app1'
];

<?php
return [
    'cookie' => 'app2'
];
```

after that **CLEAR YOUR BROWSER'S COOKIE**! (This is important!)
Without clearing, your last login behaviour will still conflict and the show can't go on.

That's it!
You can have multiple Laravel site which is duplicated from one another on different subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, your session will be terminated, given that they are all stored in the same table.

Basically, you need to have a different config for each of your multisite.

Go to `app/bootstrap/start.php`

Replace this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
   'local' => array('homestead'),
));
```

With this(example):

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment([
    "app1"   => ["app1.mysite.com"],
    "app2" => ["app2.mysite.com"]
]);
```

Then in your `app\config` folder, create two new folders `app1` and `app2`.

Whatever config files you place in them, will be loaded when the respective websites are visited.

If a config file is not present, the global default will be loaded.

Lastly, no need to have a different app folder for each website, unless you want a clear separation of concerns.

[Read more about multisites](https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-multisites-26cdc75e4810)

Comment: Thanks for pointing the link... A good read indeed. But this app acts like CLIENTS and will be distributed to several servers where they will "stand-alone" without having multiple Laravel installation.

Comment: though I've seems to find a lead where the session collides.. The posted is nice and can be a good reference for those who want to build a centralized app... whereas my case is distributed app

Comment: Glad you managed to solve this. If you are storing your sessions in a db table, i recommend creating a session table for each site, so that you can flush them when necessary.