# Two Laravel Apps in one host only one app can login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two Laravel 5.2 Apps in one host, one for production and other for staging. Both have their own database respectively. The problem is, whenever I login with one app, other app would fail to login. Anyone know how to deal with it?

I found an answer but it's not working [2 Laravel apps, only one can login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299404/2-laravel-apps-only-one-can-login)

Here's my configuration for session.php

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'cookie' => env('SESSION_NAME', 'laravel_local'),
'path' => '/',
'domain' => null,
```

Comment: What driver did you use for session storing?

Comment: And are both staging and production application accessing the right DB? How about the cookie Just to make sure. Then, try to edit `'domain' => '.yoursite.com',` in your `session.php` for each environment.

Comment: only file driver, but it stored into separate path, I'm adding my session.php config

Comment: what is `path` means relative path or absolute path ? So if it is '/' then it is on root ???

Comment: Yes, it should be the root of your app. Try to check the browser cookie, then see the domain column. Does if differ between staging and production?

Comment: it's now differ, thanks Edwin. It should be differ by cookie name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear the cookie that is used to reference your session is being shared between both apps.

Make sure both apps have a different value for the `cookie` config in the `config/session.php` config file.

```
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
```

Alternatively if your using .env files (which I noticed you are) to set the cookie name, make sure you change the appropriate variable in the .env file for each app.

Be sure to clear your browsers cookies after making the change.

If possible creating a subdomain like `staging.yoursite.com` for the staging app would be an ideal solution as it would prevent cookies being shared between the two applications.

Comment: thanks guys, it have worked. I put different name for cookie and domain by using env var

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have this app tree:

```
/path/to/web/root
    |_app1
    |   |_all
    |   |_laravel
    |   |_folders
    |   |_and
    |   |_public
    |
    |_app2
        |_all
        |_laravel
        |_folders
        |_and
        |_public
```

If you can mannage DNS records, i recomend to create two virtual servers...

The first, for example, `app1.application.com` that point to `/path/to/web/root/app1/public`

And the seccond, for example `app2.application.com` that point to `/path/to/web/root/app2/public`

> In your case, yo may want to use something like `prod.application.com` and `staging.application.com`

---

## Configure Virtual Server

#### If you are using apache, your Virtual Server configuration file may look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName app1.application.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/web/root/app1/public

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    <Directory /path/to/web/root/app1/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

#### If you are using Nginx, your Virtual Server configuration file may look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /path/to/web/root/app1/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name sigesi.tk www.sigesi.tk;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The configuration files should be saved into the web server configuration directory (`/etc/apache2` or `/etc/nginx`), inside `sites-aviable` directory.

Then you must run `sudo a2ensite <fileName>` (for Apache), or `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-aviable/<fileName> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<fileName>` (for nginx)...

And finally you must restart the webserver...

Hope this help.

Regards.